# How to know if a tag is a fast foward to another in a BARE repository?

Tags: git, teamcity

We want to make a build validation, we want to make sure the new version has all commits from the previous one. We are tagging each new version.

We are using: **git merge nextversiontag --no-commit --ff-only**, but this command works only on a full repository. Team City 8 clones a bare repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether you can fast-forward from one tag to another, then that's just simply asking the question: "Is the old tag reachable from the new tag by following parent-references along the commit graph?"

You can answer that question by using the following:

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <old-tag> <new-tag>; echo $?
```

If the output is `0`, then the old tag is reachable from the new tag, and if it's `1`, then it's not. `$?` is Bash syntax for the error code of the last command.

If you were planning on doing something else for your build validation, then you'll need to update your question to clarify what it is that you were planning to do.

Comment: That worked, thx. Can you tell me what echo $? && echo $? || echo $? does?

Comment: Just wondering: is the `&& ... || ...` to avoid exiting if `-e` is set?  `<command>; echo $?` is easier to type :-)

Comment: @torek that would be easier, I'll update my answer to that, thanks!

Comment: @Cupcake, is the option "--is-ancestor" specific to some version of git.  I have git 1.7.1 and I issued the command what you have explained, but it says, as below:
     git merge-base --is-ancestor master test1_branch
error: unknown option `is-ancestor'

Comment: @user1562655 it's only available [since version 1.8.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.4/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt#L73-74). Why are you using such an ancient version of Git?

Comment: No specific reason for using git 1.7.1.  Just that I have not upgraded after I have installed it.  Thanks for this information..